# How do I format this set of integers?

Tags: perl

I am reading this string from a file

```
my ($mon, $dy, $yr, $hr, $min, @rain) = split;
```

I then format the real (float) part as follows

```
$_ = sprintf "%6.1f", $_ foreach @rain;
```

When I print

```
print OUT " $mon $dy $yr $hr $min ", join(" ", @rain), "\n";
```

I want all the date elements to have fixed integer lengths like 4 for the year and two for the rest. currently I get two integer places then one, for month and for day.

I will appreciate assistance.
here is sample data, with $mon, $dy, $yr, $hr, $min, @rain in that order.

```
5 6 19 12 30   23.2   45.1    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.6    4.9   50.6
5 6 19 12 45   22.9   45.6    0.0    0.0    1.0    3.1    4.6  145.8
5 6 19 1 00   22.5   46.4    0.0    0.0    1.0    0.0    0.0  179.0
5 6 19 1 15   22.3   47.6    0.0    0.0    1.0    0.6    3.1   80.9
5 6 19 1 30   22.3   48.2    0.0    0.0    1.0    2.0    4.1   49.8
```

Comment: Can you add sample values to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably looking for the following piece of code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'rain.txt';        # Specify desired output filename

my $format = "%2d %2d %4d %2d %2d" . " %5.1f" x 8 . "\n";

open OUT, "> $filename"
        or die "Couldn't open $filename";

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    s/\s+/ /g;                    # strip unneeded spaces before split

    my @data = split ' ';         # put read data in a array

    printf $format, @data;        # print data on the screen
    printf OUT $format, @data;    # print data into the file
}

close OUT;

__DATA__
5 6 19 12 30   23.2   45.1    0.0    0.0    1.0    1.6    4.9   50.6
5 6 19 12 45   22.9   45.6    0.0    0.0    1.0    3.1    4.6  145.8
5 6 19 1 00   22.5   46.4    0.0    0.0    1.0    0.0    0.0  179.0
5 6 19 1 15   22.3   47.6    0.0    0.0    1.0    0.6    3.1   80.9
5 6 19 1 30   22.3   48.2    0.0    0.0    1.0    2.0    4.1   49.8
```

Generated output

```
 5  6   19 12 30  23.2  45.1   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.6   4.9  50.6
 5  6   19 12 45  22.9  45.6   0.0   0.0   1.0   3.1   4.6 145.8
 5  6   19  1  0  22.5  46.4   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0 179.0
 5  6   19  1 15  22.3  47.6   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.6   3.1  80.9
 5  6   19  1 30  22.3  48.2   0.0   0.0   1.0   2.0   4.1  49.8
```

Answer (score 4):

You've already used [sprintf](http://p3rl.org/sprintf), you can use it again to format the dates, or use [printf](http://p3rl.org/printf) directly:

```
printf '%2d %2d %4d %2d %2d', $mon, $dy, $yr, $hr, $min;
print map sprintf(' %6.1f', $_), @rain;
print "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried this. It does not give any error, but I do not see any change in the output. I am writing this to a file.

Comment: Then you need to use `print OUT` and `printf OUT`.